# How to enable mod_wsgi after pip install

Tags: python, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

On Ubuntu 14.04 I've upgraded to Python 2.7.11 using apt-get, and installed mod_wsgi using `sudo pip install mod_wsgi`.  Now, how do I enable mod_wsgi in Apache?  The install instructions (https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html) only mention building from source..

I've figured out that mod_wsgi-py27.so is in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mod_wsgi/server`, but not sure if I'm supposed to do the rest of the installation by manually editing apache config files..?

This is going to be a production machine that is managed through Puppet by the ops team (iow, it doesn't sound like mod_wsgi-express would be the way to go, but maybe I'm wrong..?)

**Update:** I might have gotten it to work by apt-get installing the (old) system version, and then hand-editing `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load` to point to the pip-installed (new) `mod_wsgi-py27.so`. Not sure if this is copacetic, however everything in `wsgi.conf` is commented out by default so maybe..?

Comment: You need to enable the module in apache. You can see this example with mod_rewrite. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Yes, `a2enmod mod_wsgi` is the normal way to enable apache modules on Ubuntu/Debian, but that requires the .load and .conf files to be present in /etc/apache2/mods-available first..

Comment: You could just install mod_wsgi the usual way from the repository `sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-wsgi`.

Comment: @alpha1554 no, can't do that since that module is (a) version 3.4, which is an insecure version, and (b) it is compiled with Python 2.7.6 -- which means it would run a different Python from what I just installed.

Answer (score 1):

While `mod_wsgi-express` might be great and is highly recommended for the simple set-up, it does have a `setup-server` command:

```
mod_wsgi-express setup-server ./my_wsgi.py
```

That creates a config directory with `apachectl`, etc. Have a look in that directory to see which `httpd.conf` directives should be necessary.